# Force entity refresh after update

Tags: nhibernate

I'm using an entity that has properties computed by view. In my sample scenario:

1. I'm getting the entity from database & I'm changing a few properties of this entity
2. I'm saving this entity session.Update(entity)
3. I'm calling session.Refresh(entity) , as some columns computed by the view can change as a result of my changes.

So NHibernate if forced to have three trips to database.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have only two trips:

1. I'm getting the entity from database & I'm changing a few properties of this entity
2. I'm saving this entity session.Update(entity) & refreshing in one database trip.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You have to issue three SQL commands: select, update, select. NHibernate does support batching but it batches together inserts or updates, not mixed commands.

Aditionally, NHibernate supports [Generated Properties](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-generated), so you don't have to update those columns by hand (it still requires a roundtrip, but it's transparent)

Comment: Generated Properties? Awesome, i'll try it